Loguru OSError. Fail randomly during process
Im using loguru and watch for file creation in a folder. I have two loguru logger one output to the console and one output to a log file
    logger.add(os.path.join(log_dir, "loghandler_{time:YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss}.log"), 
            rotation="5 minutes", 
            retention="7 days",  # Keep logs for 7 days
            compression=None,
            format="{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss} - {level: <8} - {message}",
            level="TRACE",
            encoding="utf-8")    # No compression or additional suffix

    # Add a new logger with a custom format
    logger.add(
        sys.stdout,
        format="{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss} <level>{level: <8}</level> | <level>{message}</level>",
        level="TRACE"
    )

It was working fine for a few days and then suddern logging error occur and it stop logging to the log file, however the one to console still works. I am very confused and cant seem to find the cause for this. the error message is this:
--- Logging error in Loguru Handler #1 ---
Record was: {'elapsed': datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=1592, microseconds=325057), 'exception': None, 'extra': {}, 'file': (name='transfer_script.py', path='C:\\script\\transfer_script.py'), 'function': 'on_created', 'level': (name='TRACE', no=5, icon='✏'), 'line': 46, 'message': 'New file detected:X1018202411150006__081104_11262024.CSV', 'module': 'transfer_script', 'name': '__main__', 'process': (id=9112, name='MainProcess'), 'thread': (id=10192, name='Thread-1'), 'time': datetime(2024, 11, 26, 10, 34, 52, 986173, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800), 'China Standard Time'))}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\conda\envs\spea\Lib\site-packages\loguru\_handler.py", line 206, in emit
    self._sink.write(str_record)
  File "C:\conda\envs\spea\Lib\site-packages\loguru\_file_sink.py", line 206, in write
    self._file.write(message)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
--- End of logging error ---

I have tested for a few days , where it works fine for a while and then sudden error and keep throwing error since.
